# Recursion not working as we expect

Tags: java, recursion

for a project, we have a table in our database that contains files and folders.

It goes like this

```
CREATE TABLE files (
    file_id INT PRIMARY_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    file_type varchar(255) NOT NULL, // can be any mimetype or "dir" if it's a directory
    file_parent_id INT NOT NULL // contains the id of the directory the file is in
);
```

We'd like to be able to delete a folder, and when we do that, delete everything in that folder.
A recursive function seem appropriate but we have a hard time wrapping our heads around the concept of recursion and how to achieve what we want.
Atm we thought we had a good algorithm but it's only deleting the first folder (and it's content) of each folder.

```
public void deleteRecursively(Client client, int dir_id) {
        ResultSet res = FileModel.getSubdirs(client, dir_id);
        ResultSet files = FileModel.findFilesInDir(client, dir_id);
        if (res == null) {
            try {
                FileModel tmp = null;
                if (files != null) {
                    // deleting files in cur_dir
                    while (files.next()) {
                        tmp = FileModel.find(client, files.getInt("f_id"));
                        if (tmp != null) {
                            tmp.deleteMe(client);
                        }
                        tmp = null;
                    }
                }
                // deleting current_dir
                tmp = FileModel.find(client, dir_id);
                if (tmp != null) {
                    tmp.deleteMe(client);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Logs.error(
                        e,
                        Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2]
                                .getLineNumber() + " : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            try {
                while (res.next()) {
                    this.deleteRecursively(client, res.getInt("f_id"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Logs.error(
                        e,
                        Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2]
                                .getLineNumber() + " : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT : FileModel

```
package com.dev.model;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import com.dev.logs.Logs;
import com.dev.main.Client;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

public class FileModel {
    private int f_id = -1;
    private int f_owner_id;
    private int f_parent_id;
    private String f_path;
    private String f_name;
    private double f_size;
    private String f_type;

    public FileModel(int f_owner_id, int f_parent_id, String f_path,
            String f_name, int f_size, String f_type) {
        this.f_owner_id = f_owner_id;
        this.f_parent_id = f_parent_id;
        this.f_path = f_path;
        this.f_name = f_name;
        this.f_size = f_size;
        this.f_type = f_type;
    }

    public FileModel(ResultSet res) {
        try {
            this.f_id = res.getInt("f_id");
            this.f_owner_id = res.getInt("f_owner_id");
            this.f_path = res.getString("f_path");
            this.f_size = res.getDouble("f_size");
            this.f_type = res.getString("f_type");
            this.f_name = res.getString("f_name");
            this.f_parent_id = res.getInt("f_parent_id");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logs.error(e, "Not provided", "Error Initializing file");
        }
    }

    public static ResultSet getSubdirs(Client client, int dir_id) {
        client.getDb().connect();
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet res = null;
        try {
            stmt = (PreparedStatement) client
                    .getDb()
                    .getCon()
                    .prepareStatement(
                            "SELECT * from files WHERE f_parent_id = ? AND f_type = ?");
            stmt.setString(1, Integer.toString(dir_id));
            stmt.setString(2, "dir");
            res = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (!res.isBeforeFirst()) {
                return null;
            }
            return res;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logs.error(e,
                    Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber()
                            + " : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static FileModel find(Client client, int id) {
        client.getDb().connect();
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        FileModel ret = null;
        ResultSet res = null;
        try {
            stmt = (PreparedStatement) client
                    .getDb()
                    .getCon()
                    .prepareStatement(
                            "SELECT * from files WHERE f_id = ? AND f_owner_id = ?");
            stmt.setString(1, Integer.toString(id));
            stmt.setString(2, Integer.toString(client.getId()));
            res = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (!res.next()) {
                System.out.println("No records found");
                client.sendError("No file found for that id");
                return null;
            } else {
                ret = new FileModel(res);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logs.error(e,
                    Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber()
                            + " : " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static ResultSet findFilesInDir(Client client, int dir_id) {
        client.getDb().connect();
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet res = null;
        try {
            stmt = (PreparedStatement) client
                    .getDb()
                    .getCon()
                    .prepareStatement(
                            "SELECT * from files WHERE f_parent_id = ?");
            stmt.setString(1, Integer.toString(dir_id));
            res = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (res.isBeforeFirst()) {
                return res;
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logs.error(e, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int saveToDb(Client client) {
        client.getDb().connect();
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;

        try {
            if (this.f_id == -1) {
                stmt = (PreparedStatement) client
                        .getDb()
                        .getCon()
                        .prepareStatement(
                                "INSERT into files (f_owner_id,f_parent_id,f_path,f_name,f_size,f_type,f_created,f_modified) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW(),NOW())");
                stmt.setString(1, Integer.toString(this.f_owner_id));
                stmt.setString(2, Integer.toString(this.f_parent_id));
                stmt.setString(3, this.f_path);
                stmt.setString(4, this.f_name);
                stmt.setString(5, Double.toString(this.f_size));
                stmt.setString(6, this.f_type);
                return stmt.executeUpdate();
            } else {

                stmt = (PreparedStatement) client
                        .getDb()
                        .getCon()
                        .prepareStatement(
                                "UPDATE files SET f_parent_id = ?, f_name = ?, f_size= ?, f_type = ?, f_modified = NOW() WHERE f_id = ? AND f_owner_id = ?");
                stmt.setString(1, Integer.toString(this.f_parent_id));
                stmt.setString(2, this.f_name);
                stmt.setString(3, Double.toString(this.f_size));
                stmt.setString(4, this.f_type);
                stmt.setString(5, Integer.toString(this.f_id));
                stmt.setString(6, Integer.toString(this.f_owner_id));
                return stmt.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logs.error(e, "Not provided", e.getMessage());
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void deleteMe(Client client) {
        try {
            if (this.f_id > 0) {
                client.getDb().connect();
                if (this.f_type.equals("dir") == false) {
                    File file = new File(this.f_path + this.f_name);
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        file.delete();
                    }
                }
                client.getDb().delete(
                        "DELETE FROM files WHERE f_id = '"
                                + Integer.toString(this.f_id) + "'");
                client.getDb().delete(
                        "DELETE FROM file_shared WHERE fs_file_id = '"
                                + Integer.toString(this.f_id) + "'");
                client.getDb().delete(
                        "DELETE FROM public_links WHERE pl_file_id = '"
                                + Integer.toString(this.f_id) + "'");
                client.getDb().disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logs.error(e, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public int getF_parent_id() {
        return f_parent_id;
    }

    public void setF_parent_id(int f_parent_id) {
        this.f_parent_id = f_parent_id;
    }

    public int getF_id() {
        return f_id;
    }

    public void setF_id(int f_id) {
        this.f_id = f_id;
    }

    public int getF_owner_id() {
        return f_owner_id;
    }

    public void setF_owner_id(int f_owner_id) {
        this.f_owner_id = f_owner_id;
    }

    public String getF_path() {
        return f_path;
    }

    public void setF_path(String f_path) {
        this.f_path = f_path;
    }

    public double getF_size() {
        return f_size;
    }

    public void setF_size(double f_size) {
        this.f_size = f_size;
    }

    public String getF_type() {
        return f_type;
    }

    public void setF_type(String f_type) {
        this.f_type = f_type;
    }

    public String getF_name() {
        return f_name;
    }

    public void setF_name(String f_name) {
        this.f_name = f_name;
    }

}
```

Where did we go wrong ?

Comment: Can you show `FileModel.getSubdirs` implementation or better the whole class?

Comment: It's done, I hope it will help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your are doing deleting in wrong order.

I think it should be something like this:

```
public void deleteRecursively(Client client, int dir_id) {
        ResultSet res = FileModel.getSubdirs(client, dir_id);

        /if we have some sub folders, we must do recursive call for these folders
        if (res != null) {
            try {
                while (res.next()) {
                    this.deleteRecursively(client, res.getInt("f_id"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //....
            }
        }


        ResultSet files = FileModel.findFilesInDir(client, dir_id);

        if (files != null) {
            // deleting files in cur_dir
            while (files.next()) {
               tmp = FileModel.find(client, files.getInt("f_id"));
               if (tmp != null) {
                  tmp.deleteMe(client);
               }
               tmp = null;
            }
         }

        // deleting current_dir
        tmp = FileModel.find(client, dir_id);
        if (tmp != null) {
            tmp.deleteMe(client);
        }

    }
```